# Why is there additional space?

Tags: spacing, conditionals, line-spacing

I try using a specific section only if a variable is defined. Everything seems to work, however there is an additional space between the name of person B and the address, although the same code is used as for person A...

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\AnredeMieterA}{Mrs.}
\newcommand{\NameMieterA}{Person A}
\newcommand{\AdresseMieterA}{address A}
\newcommand{\AnredeMieterB}{Mrs.}
\newcommand{\NameMieterB}{Person B}
\newcommand{\AdresseMieterB}{address B}

\begin{document}

\medskip \textbf{\AnredeMieterA\ \NameMieterA}\\ 
\medskip wohnhaft \textbf{\AdresseMieterA}\\ 
\ifx\NameMieterB\undefined
\else
\medskip sowie \\
\medskip \textbf{\AnredeMieterB\ \NameMieterB}\\ 
\medskip wohnhaft \textbf{\AdresseMieterB}\\ 
\fi

\end{document}
```

Why?

[image]

Comment: You are adding `\medskip ` space.  `\medskip Mrs.PersonB\\ ` adds space after the linebreak

Comment: the code for A is different as in `\medskip Mrs.PersonA\\ ` the `\medskip`is in vertical mode so adds a vertical space at that point

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- but there's a `\medskip` also between `Mrs, Person A` and the address, but no extra space there.  ???

Comment: try  `\medskip aaa bbb ccc ddd  eee \medskip aaa bbb ccc ddd  eee \medskip aaa bbb ccc ddd  eee \medskip aaa bbb ccc ddd  eee \medskip aaa bbb ccc ddd  eee`   (only) the first `\medskp` adds space directly, if you use `\vspace` mid-paragraph it adds space after the current line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes no space has been added after the first line

Comment: use `\par` not `\\ `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you for the quick explanations.

Comment: it was too late at night to make real examples  but @cabohah filled it out nicely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\medskip` is `\vspace{\medskipamount}` and usage of `\vspace` in horizontal mode does not add the vertical space immediately but after the current line.

Because `\\` in justified text does not make a paragraph, you are still in horizontal mode after the `\\`. So the `\medskip` before `wohnhaft` adds the space before `sowie` not before `wohnhaft`.

As David explained in a comment, the result would be different with `\par` instead of `\\`. This is because, after `\par` you are always in vertical mode and in vertical mode `\vspace` adds the vertical space immediately:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\AnredeMieterA}{Mrs.}
\newcommand{\NameMieterA}{Person A}
\newcommand{\AdresseMieterA}{address A}
\newcommand{\AnredeMieterB}{Mrs.}
\newcommand{\NameMieterB}{Person B}
\newcommand{\AdresseMieterB}{address B}

\begin{document}

\medskip \textbf{\AnredeMieterA\ \NameMieterA}\par
\medskip wohnhaft \textbf{\AdresseMieterA}\par
\ifx\NameMieterB\undefined
\else
\medskip sowie \par
\medskip \textbf{\AnredeMieterB\ \NameMieterB}\par
\medskip wohnhaft \textbf{\AdresseMieterB}\par
\fi

\end{document}
```

Another suggestion would be to use the optional argument of `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\AnredeMieterA}{Mrs.}
\newcommand{\NameMieterA}{Person A}
\newcommand{\AdresseMieterA}{address A}
\newcommand{\AnredeMieterB}{Mrs.}
\newcommand{\NameMieterB}{Person B}
\newcommand{\AdresseMieterB}{address B}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\AnredeMieterA\ \NameMieterA}\\[\medskipamount] 
wohnhaft \textbf{\AdresseMieterA}\\[\medskipamount]
\ifx\NameMieterB\undefined
\else
sowie \\[\medskipamount]
\textbf{\AnredeMieterB\ \NameMieterB}\\[\medskipamount]
wohnhaft \textbf{\AdresseMieterB}
\fi

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\AnredeMieterA}{Mrs.}
\newcommand{\NameMieterA}{Person A}
\newcommand{\AdresseMieterA}{address A}
\newcommand{\AnredeMieterB}{Mrs.}
\newcommand{\NameMieterB}{Person B}
\newcommand{\AdresseMieterB}{address B}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\AnredeMieterA\ \NameMieterA}%
\\[\medskipamount] wohnhaft \textbf{\AdresseMieterA}%
\ifx\NameMieterB\undefined
\else
\\[\medskipamount] sowie
\\[\medskipamount] \textbf{\AnredeMieterB\ \NameMieterB}
\\[\medskipamount] wohnhaft \textbf{\AdresseMieterB}
\fi

\end{document}
```

But because, I would avoid `\\` in justified text, I would suggest to explicitly switch to ragged text, either using `\raggedright` or:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\AnredeMieterA}{Mrs.}
\newcommand{\NameMieterA}{Person A}
\newcommand{\AdresseMieterA}{address A}
\newcommand{\AnredeMieterB}{Mrs.}
\newcommand{\NameMieterB}{Person B}
\newcommand{\AdresseMieterB}{address B}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{\AnredeMieterA\ \NameMieterA}%
\\[\medskipamount] wohnhaft \textbf{\AdresseMieterA}%
\ifx\NameMieterB\undefined
\else
\\[\medskipamount] sowie
\\[\medskipamount] \textbf{\AnredeMieterB\ \NameMieterB}
\\[\medskipamount] wohnhaft \textbf{\AdresseMieterB}
\fi
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

All examples result in the same vertical space between the lines of the block, but may differ in vertical distance before or after the block, if there would be text before or after it. The first example could also differ, if `\parskip` would be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. That helped me understand everything better. In my case I am in a `scrreprt` document and in a `\begin{addmargin}` environment. There `\par` does not work. But with your help I was able to make it work!